# JAXB marshalling a map without adapter

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a Map and I want to marshal it to XML. As long as there are plenty of maps of different types I really don't want to write a custom XmlAdapter for each map.
I have XmlAdapters for all classes that I use as keys. When I marshal this classes standalone they work perfectly, but when I marshal the maps the keys are just ignored. All I get is the following XML:

```
<entry>
    <key/>
    <value>
        <id>1</id>
        <property>something</property>
    </value>
</entry>
```

What I want instead is:

```
<entry>
    <key>
        <property>something</property>
    </key>
    <value>
        <id>1</id>
        <property>something</property>
    </value>
</entry>
```

Is there a way to achieve the required result without coding a custom XmlAdapter for each map?

Comment: The following will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html

Comment: Thanks. But I have no problems marshaling  <String, Object> map. The problem arises when I use a custom class as map key

Comment: There isn't anything special you. We'd to do for that use case.  What issue are you running into when you try it?

Comment: Please, add your custom class code.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything special you need to do with JAXB and `java.util.Map`.  I will demonstrate below with an example.

### Java Model

**Foo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private Map<Bar, Bar> bars = new HashMap<Bar, Bar>();

    public Map<Bar, Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(Map<Bar, Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

}
```

**Bar**

```
public class Bar {

    private String baz;

    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Bar bar1 = new Bar();
        bar1.setBaz("Hello");

        Bar bar2 = new Bar();
        bar2.setBaz("World");

        foo.getBars().put(bar1, bar2);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bars>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <baz>Hello</baz>
            </key>
            <value>
                <baz>World</baz>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </bars>
</foo>
```

### For More Information

I have written more about JAXB and `java.util.Map` on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html